# Implement a monitoring thread without lock?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that sends messages to a channel as well as updating some of its own fields. How do I implement a monitoring thread that looks (read only) at its internal fields periodically?

I can write it using a `Arc<Mutex<T>>` wrapper, but I feel it is not that efficient as `A::x` could have been `i32` which is stored and updated on the stack. Is there any better way to do it without the locks?

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
use std::{thread, time};

struct A {
    x: Arc<Mutex<i32>>,
    y: Sender<i32>,
}

impl A {
    fn do_some_loop(&mut self) {
        let sleep_time = time::Duration::from_millis(200);
        // This is a long running thread.
        for x in 1..1000000 {
            *self.x.lock().unwrap() = x;
            self.y.send(x);
            thread::sleep(sleep_time);
        }
    }
}

fn test() {
    let (sender, recever) = channel();
    let x = Arc::new(Mutex::new(1));
    let mut a = A { x: x.clone(), y: sender };

    thread::spawn(move || {
        // Monitor every 10 secs.
        let sleep_time = time::Duration::from_millis(10000);
        loop {
            thread::sleep(sleep_time);
            println!("{}", *x.lock().unwrap());
        }

    });
    a.do_some_loop();
}
```

Comment: *stored and updated on the stack* — is that the main issue? Do you already realize why not using something equivalent to a lock (be it a `Mutex`, `RwLock`, etc.) is **required** to ensure correctness? Asked another way, what level of experience do you have with multithreaded programming?

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do, the stuff in `std::sync::atomic` might be what you're looking for. Be careful though, lock-free multithreaded programming is very difficult to do correctly. Here's an intro to the topic: http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/